# Internet connectivity does not work in Ubuntu Server 14.04 on Windows 8 VirtualBox host

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, virtualbox-networking

I have a PC with Windows 8, with Oracle VirtualBox installed on it. In the File>Preferences>Network menu in VirtualBox, I have created three host-only networks:

1. Host-only network 1 - 10.10.10.1
2. Host-only network 2 - 10.20.20.1
3. Host-only network 3 - 192.168.100.1

with all of them having a netmask 255.255.255.0.

I have also created three VMs as listed below:

1. **Controller** is attached to Host-only network adapter 1 on the first adapter and NAT on the second.
2. **Network** is attached to Host-only network adapter 2 on the first adapter and Host-only network adapter 3 on the second.
3. **Compute** is attached to Host-only network adapter 3 on the first adapter and Host-only network adapter 2 on the second.

On the controller node, I configured the settings as per below:

- In `/etc/hosts`: Added 10.10.10.11 as **controller**, 10.10.10.11 as **network** and 10.10.10.13 as **compute**
- In `/etc/network/interfaces`:

  ```
  auto eth0
      iface eth0 inet static
      address 10.10.10.10
      netmask 255.255.255.0

  auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet dhcp
  ```
- In `/etc/resolv.conf`: Added `8.8.8.8` as nameserver

The problem is that Internet connectivity does not seem to work. `apt-get update` fails to fetch index files from every server and `ping google.com` returns `unknown host google.com`.

How can I fix internet connectivity?

Answer (score 0):

You might have configured the wrong network interface in **Controller**'s `/etc/network/interfaces`. Find the correct network interface name and modify `/etc/network/interfaces`, replacing eth1 with the correct interface name:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 net dhcp
```

You might also want to remove one of the two stanzas in `/etc/network/interfaces`, either:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.10.10.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

OR

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

as they might conflict.